# empty result when parsing from xml into DataTable - c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

i get an empty Datatable when parsing xml file with xmlReader and import it into one DataTable , its necessary for me to save it into Data table so i can import it later into sql server with sqlbulkcopy
easily (i have huge number of lines),

what i try

```
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\neyma\test/W.xml"))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("EventID");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Computer");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetUserName");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetDomainName");
            
            DataRow myDataRow;
            myDataRow = dataTable.NewRow();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {

                    switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                    {
                        case "EventID":

                            myDataRow["EventID"] = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                           
                            break;
                        case "Computer":
                            myDataRow["Computer"] = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                            break;
                        case "Data":

                            if (reader.GetAttribute("Name") == "TargetUserName")
                                myDataRow["TargetUserName"] = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                            else if (reader.GetAttribute("Name") == "TargetDomainName")
                            
                                myDataRow["TargetDomainName"] = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                            break;
```

sample from xml

```
<eventxml>
<Event <EventID>36</EventID><Computer>NH</Computer><EventData><Data Name="TargetUserName">TER.go</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">%4</Data></EventData></Event>
<Event <EventID>51</EventID><Computer>NQ-RS1-.ov</Computer><EventData><Data Name="TargetUserName">TERMSRiv</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">%%4</Data></EventData></Event>
<Event <EventID>536</EventID><Computer>CRS1.ov</Computer><EventData><Data Name="TargetUserName">TERRov</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">%%144</Data></EventData></Event>
</eventxml>
```

Comment: Sample XML data (as text) and expected results would help

Comment: @Charlieface i add the sample and the expected result is a dataTable contain the information inside the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is going to be much easier to do with `XDocument` and LINQ

```cs
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    {"EventID", typeof(string)},
    {"Computer", typeof(string)},
    {"TargetUserName", typeof(string)},
    {"TargetDomainName", typeof(string)},
} };

foreach (var node in xDoc.Root.Elements("Event"))
{
    var data = node.Element("EventData");
    table.Rows.Add(
        node.Element("EventID").Value,
        node.Element("Computer").Value,
        data.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "TargetUserName").Value,
        data.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "TargetDomainName").Value
    );
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TzuOzH)

Another option is to pass the whole XML into SQL and parse it using XQuery.

Comment: how i print the dataTable to check if its empty or not

Comment: Console.WriteLine(table); show nothing

Comment: See the fiddle link, also VS debugger can view the whole datatable using the QuickWatch

Comment: i got this error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'

Comment: Your original XML is invalid. I see missing `>` after `<Event` on each line

Comment: i add > to each line and still stuck on the same error so i guess i cant deal with xdoc method

Comment: i check and its desplay no error were found

Comment: Are you using `XDocument.Parse` or `XDocument.Load`? Do you have a file or a variable? You need the former for a variable, the latter for a file

Comment: good point now its work but still get empty result

Comment: Then your XML probably doesn't match what you put in the question. Please give a [mcve] where the sample XML matches the shape of your XML (don't need all the lines, but don't remove root/parent nodes)

Comment: all root/parent nodes are exist on the sample

Comment: Then construct a dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/TzuOzH showing your xml and the problem

Comment: i put > and re try to do it with doc.Load instead of doc.parse now i get this error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: As I said: construct a fiddle