# problem when parsing from xml to a dataTable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable

when i parsing xml file and save it into a DataTable all the rows save on one column
how to make it save every classs on one column on the DataTable

sample from the code

```
       using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\neyma\test/W.xml"))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("EventID");
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("Computer");
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetUserName");
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetDomainName");
                    
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.IsStartElement())
                        {
        
                            switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                            {
                                case "EventID":
        
        data.EventID= reader.ReadInnerXml();
        dt.Rows.Add(data.EventID);
                                   
                                    break;
                                case "Computer":
        data.Computer= reader.ReadInnerXml();
        dt.Rows.Add(data.Computer);
                                    break;
                                case "Data":
        
                                    if (reader.GetAttribute("Name") == "TargetUserName")
           data.TargetUserName= reader.ReadInnerXml();
        dt.Rows.Add(data.TargetUserName);
                            else if (reader.GetAttribute("Name") =="TargetDomainName")
                                    
                                        data.TargetDomainName= reader.ReadInnerXml();
        
                                                 dt.Rows.Add(data.TargetDomainName);
                                                
                                    break;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => string.Join(", ", r.ItemArray))));
```

and i try to parsing directly to the dataTable but its given me an empty result so i try to save it into classes first then from classes to a dataTable and its work good but i don't know the syntax for decide which column to insert

the output:

```
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215101, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215100, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215099, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215098, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215097, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215096, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215095, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
851215094, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

what im looking for :

```
 5136, 851215098, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
    851215101, 5136, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
   ,
    
    851215097,5136 , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
    851215096,5136 , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
    
    851215095,5136 , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
    
    851215094,5136 , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

sample from xml

```
<eventxml>
<Event <EventID>36</EventID><Computer>NH</Computer><EventData><Data Name="TargetUserName">TER.go</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">%4</Data></EventData></Event>
<Event <EventID>51</EventID><Computer>NQ-RS1-.ov</Computer><EventData><Data Name="TargetUserName">TERMSRiv</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">%%4</Data></EventData></Event>
<Event <EventID>536</EventID><Computer>CRS1.ov</Computer><EventData><Data Name="TargetUserName">TERRov</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">%%144</Data></EventData></Event>
</eventxml>
```

problem solved by @jdweng

and for me if u have this error `('Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'element'))` try to make the first two lines like the latest like this `Int EventID = (Int)xEvent.Descendants("EventID").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: What does the XML look like?

Comment: just added the sample @HereticMonkey

Comment: Does this answer your question? [empty result when parsing from xml into DataTable - c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73135581/empty-result-when-parsing-from-xml-into-datatable-c-sharp-net) You asked this yesterday, I answered it and you entirely ignored it when creating this question

Comment: @Charlieface no i get an error when use ur method and i send it there , im trying another way now

Comment: Please do not edit "solved" into the title. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers) for what you should do when someone answers your question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("EventID",typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Computer",typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetUserName",typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetDomainName",typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement xEvent in doc.Descendants("Event"))
            {
                int EventID = (int)xEvent.Element("EventID");
                string Computer = (string)xEvent.Element("Computer");
                string TargetUserName = (string)xEvent.Descendants("Data").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "TargetUserName").FirstOrDefault();
                string TargetDomainName = (string)xEvent.Descendants("Data").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "TargetDomainName").FirstOrDefault();

                dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { EventID, Computer, TargetUserName, TargetDomainName });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this error shown :////////////  'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'element')'

Comment: Which line?  The only line that may give error is the EventID.  Unless the xml file is not found.

Comment: I tested with your sample xml.  There were some missing closing brackets that I had to add to XML.  But otherwise code worked.

Comment: where is the missing please

Comment: i added close brackets for every line for Event tag and delete the first two line (computer and EventID) and the two other tags is parsing and import correctly so i think the problem is with these 2 lines, do u have any suggestions

Comment: bro thank u so much i try to make it  Int EventID = (Int)xEvent.Descendants("EventID").FirstOrDefault(); and its work good i appreciate u have a good day

Comment: This answer could do with some more explanation, like why one would choose LINQ or what the code does. This is basically a "Try this:" code dump.

Comment: Also changing to following should work : int? EventID = (int?)xEvent.Element("EventID");

Comment: @HereticMonkey : Xml Linq is much simpler than OP code.

Comment: @jdweng [Edit] your answer to include more explanation. I know you're capable of better answers. I know the OP didn't do a great job with the question, but Q&A are for more than just the OP.

Comment: @HereticMonkey : My teacher said too much comments is just as bad as too little comments.  Code that is well spaced, Variables declared with type (no var), and variable names chosen properly do not need to be documented when the statements are are well understood.  Documenting this code is not going to make any easier to understand.  It is just going to make it harder to read.